# Configuring Windows Authentication with MVC (4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

While testing and developing on my local machine, code that I used to get my username on the domain with User.Identity.Name worked fine.

Now that I've published to our local server, the application keeps redirecting me to the /login.aspx?ReturnUrl= page, but I'm getting a 401 - Unauthorized error.

I can't figure out what to do next. Here's the steps I've taken so far:

- Disabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS & my project properties
- Added   to the Web.config
- Put [Authorize] on all my controllers
- Enabled Windows Authentication on my project properties

If I run the site on the local server itself, the error is a bit more detailed:

```
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

Then again I'm not sure if this error is different to the usual 401.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you have disabled anonymous authentication on iis, what authentication does it say is enabled?

Comment: What do you mean you get redirected? After you publish, the (default windows) authorization gets handled by IIS. You would only get to your application if you could provide valid credentials. Do you get a login dialog popup? Btw, what @BenRobinson is hinting at is that it does not suffice to disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication, but you must also disable forms authentication from IIS.

Comment: There isn't any authentication enabled on IIS (Anonymous, Impersonation and Forms). There is no Windows Authentication option in IIS.

There is no login popup. When I go to my app's URL, like 192.168.0.1/TheApp/  -  It automatically changes to 192.168.0.1/TheApp/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=... 

I'm already part of the AD domain, so I don't want anything to pop up, I just want it to know my username.

Comment: You either have partially installed IIS or you are not setting the application in the correct App Pool. Make sure your app is installed on a .Net 4.0 Integrated app pool

Comment: @drminnaar that's actually what I was hinting at.  You need to enable windows authentication (or some form of authentication) in iis.  If you have NO authentication then user's cannot be authenticated.  Windows authentication is an optional iis component. If you don't see it as an option then you need to install it.  How you do this depends on the version of windows on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server I was publishing to didn't have the correct Authentication types installed. Resolved.